# Getting NGINX to point to docker mattermost-preview

Tags: docker, nginx, mattermost

I'm trying to follow this: https://forum.mattermost.org/t/recipe-embedding-mattermost-in-web-applications-using-an-iframe-unsupported-recipe/10233

I'm running a dockerized version of mattermost. I am running a dockerized container of nginx. I configured my nginx according to: https://docs.mattermost.com/install/install-ubuntu-1804.html#configuring-nginx-as-a-proxy-for-mattermost-server

I have the mattermost-preview container running on localhost:8065.

I followed the steps and restart the nginx instance and visit localhost:80 but still see the default nginx welcome page.

Here's my default.conf:

```
upstream backend {
   server localhost:8065;
   keepalive 32;
}

proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=mattermost_cache:10m max_size=3g inactive=120m use_temp_path=off;

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name   localhost;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 443 http2;
   server_name    localhost_two;

   http2_push_preload on; # Enable HTTP/2 Server Push

   ssl off;
   
   location ~ /api/v[0-9]+/(users/)?websocket$ {
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       client_max_body_size 50M;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_hide_header Content-Security-Policy;
       proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
       proxy_buffers 256 16k;
       proxy_buffer_size 16k;
       client_body_timeout 60;
       send_timeout 300;
       lingering_timeout 5;
       proxy_connect_timeout 90;
       proxy_send_timeout 300;
       proxy_read_timeout 90s;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_pass http://backend;
   }

   location / {
       client_max_body_size 50M;
       proxy_set_header Connection "";
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_hide_header Content-Security-Policy;
       proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
       proxy_buffers 256 16k;
       proxy_buffer_size 16k;
       proxy_read_timeout 600s;
       proxy_cache mattermost_cache;
       proxy_cache_revalidate on;
       proxy_cache_min_uses 2;
       proxy_cache_use_stale timeout;
       proxy_cache_lock on;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_pass http://backend;
   }
}

# This block is useful for debugging TLS v1.3. Please feel free to remove this
# and use the `$ssl_early_data` variable exposed by NGINX directly should you
# wish to do so.
map $ssl_early_data $tls1_3_early_data {
  "~." $ssl_early_data;
  default "";
}
```

My nginx.conf is the default one

Comment: You appear to still be using "mattermost.example.com" as your server name which does not match "localhost" hence the server rule won't be executed. You are also performing a ssl redirect which might become tricky to setup locally.

Comment: Oh my bad, I forgot to change the server name while posting here on SO. In regards to the redirect, what can I put over there?

Comment: You may just put the code of the `listen 443` block inside the `listen 80` block and remove the 301 redirect from that one.

Comment: Okay cool, I'll give that a go!

Comment: Alas, no luck... still see the default nginx welcome page